# Excel export only weekly tickets (Support ticket website) - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel, export-to-excel

I'm currently working on Laravel for the first time and i'm stuck with an issue. I have an export excel button on my tickets list page but It exports all the tickets ever created. Is there a way to only export weekly tickets in excel format based on the current date?

excel form :

```
@foreach (\App\Tickets::All() as $ticket)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $ticket->societe}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->intervenant}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->assistance->level}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->message}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->urgence->niveau}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->statut}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->utilisateur->name}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Excel function in ticketscontroller :

```
public function exportxls(){
      Excel::create('tickets', function($excel){
        $excel->sheet('tickets', function($sheet){
          $sheet->loadView('export.ticketsexcel');
        })->export('xls');
      });
      return redirect('/');
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please expalin `weekly tickets` and how u want it?

Comment: You need a method in `App\Tickets\` that filters by date range.

Comment: So basicly for the moment my button exports elements of my tickets from all the tickets of the database. What I want is to be able to export only the tickets created each week according to the current week. I know laravel has timestamps but i don't know how it works.

Comment: I know how to filter by date range in MySQL but I don't know how to do so using Laravel, it's quite new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have sent data from controller to the view and export only weekly tickets you can modify your query.

```
public function exportxls(){
  $weeklyTickets = \App\Tickets::whereBetween('created_at', array(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days")), date('Y-m-d'))->get();

  Excel::create('tickets', function($excel) use ($weeklyTickets){
    $excel->sheet('tickets', function($sheet) use ($weeklyTickets){
      $sheet->loadView('export.ticketsexcel', array('weeklyTickets' => $weeklyTickets));
    })->export('xls');
  });
  return redirect('/');
}
```

In this function change "created_at" field according to your database field.

And in view you can modify it like this:

```
@foreach ($weeklyTickets as $ticket)
<tr>
<td>{{ $ticket->societe}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->intervenant}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->assistance->level}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->message}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->urgence->niveau}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->statut}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->utilisateur->name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried your answer but I used Tickets::whereBetween instead of \App\Tickets->whereBetween because it displayed an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR). Then I got this error : Undefined variable: weeklyTickets. Any idea why it doesn't recognize the variable?

Comment: Please check updated answer, I have passed $weeklyTickets to be used inside anonymous function.

Comment: It works, but it isn't quite what I want. Is it possible to get the tickets of Monday to Friday of the current week. For example, today is Wednesday, is it possible to get all the tickets created starting from Monday to today?